# Tag field: how to properly change list item CSS depending on list item data values

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm trying to display list items in tag field with different colors, depending on the values in their data. So I'm asking what is the proper way to change list item css depending on list item data? Should I change **fieldSubTpl** or is there any other way to do this ?
Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe are you looking for the [labelTpl](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#cfg-labelTpl) config.